# Comparing Topologies of Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How can I generally show that two metric spaces induce the same topology, for instance, in my textbook it says metric space $d(x,y$) and $\sqrt{d(x,y)}$ induce the same topology. How do I show this? Much help would be appreciated.

ok so very generally I wrote up some solution, and it goes:

Let $d^{'}=\sqrt{d}$, then we want to show that $B_d(x,\epsilon) \subseteq B_{\sqrt{d}}(x,\epsilon)$. Let $y \in B_d(x,\epsilon)$,but $d^{'}$ is the square root metric of $d$, so we have $d^{'} \le d$, hence $d^{'}(x,y)\le d(x,y)<\epsilon \implies y \in B_{\sqrt{d}}(x,\epsilon)$, therefore $B_d(x,\epsilon) \subseteq B_{\sqrt{d}}(x,\epsilon)$. is this the correct way?

Comment: Take an arbitrary open ball in $d(x,y)$ and show that it is also open in $\sqrt{(d(x,y)}$. Then take an arbitrary open ball in $\sqrt{d(x,y)}$ and show that it is also open in $d(x,y)$. Since the topology is generated by the open balls, they must then generate the same topology.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I think I get the idea intuitively, but I am lacking the technique to generally show how one open ball being open in one metric space, mean it is also open in another metric space.

Comment: Hint: $d(x,y) = r$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{d(x,y)} = \sqrt{r}$.

Comment: @ mrp @Christoph could you check if my method is correct, by the hints given?

Comment: The $\varepsilon$'s don't have to be the same for the balls. Just by seeing that $B_d(x,\varepsilon) = B_{\sqrt{d}}(x,\sqrt{\varepsilon})$ we know that the two metrics have the exact same sets of open balls.